# Backward-compatible SQL query against table with renamed column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, common-table-expression, backwards-compatibility

Let `t` be an Oracle 11g table with columns `a`, `b`. The `b` column is later renamed to `c`.

How to develop an SQL query which works against both database versions? "Works" means:

- returns columns `a`, `c`
- behaves as `select a, c from t` on new version
- behaves as `select a, b as c from t` on old version

The background is, the module with SQL query (it is actually based on Pentaho Data Integration) has deployment lifecycle which does not strictly match the deployment lifecycle of database changes. Also there seems to be no clean way of feature-flagging multiple versions of SQL query. Hence one-SQL-fits-all solution seems to be the simplest one for 100% compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution I could figure out is based on CTE:

```sql
with x(a,c) as (select * from t)
select a,c from x
```

[Db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=71222fe3e7e54fe6f48aa9aadc9c5426) demonstration on two different tables.

The obvious limitation is the number of column must stay same and there must not be any change in column order.

Answer (score 2):

You may add a virtual column that projects a new column with an old name. And after you migrate all the consuming code to the new column names, you may drop old virtual columns for free.

> ```
> create table t (
>   a int,
>   b int
> )
> ```

> ```
> insert into t
> select 1, 2 from dual union all
> select 3, 4 from dual
> ```

> ```
> create function f
> return int
> as
>   res int;
> begin
>   select sum(a) + sum(b)
>     into res
>   from t;
>   
>   return res;
> end;/
> ```

> ```
> alter table t
> rename column b to c;
>
> alter table t
> add b int generated always as (0+c) virtual
> ```

> ```
> select f()
> from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> | F() |
> | --: |
> |  10 |
> ```

> ```
> create or replace function f
> return int
> as
>   res int;
> begin
>   select sum(a) + sum(c)
>     into res
>   from t;
>   
>   return res;
> end;/
> ```

> ```
> alter table t
> drop column b
> ```

> ```
> select f()
> from dual
> ```
>
> ```
> | F() |
> | --: |
> |  10 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d1f64d609d9b78f50a6af0c27c3fab4f)*

Comment: Interesting solution providing even smoother transition between database versions. The table data does not change very often so adding `c` and later removing `b` (without using virtual column) would have essentially same effect. However I am not sure whether I can guarantee there is no consumer of table who would *strictly* expect the `b` column to be absent. Hence I prefer solution where I have not to do any followup DDL work (changing SQL is easy). Anyway thanks for answer. (The question is actually first half of harder problem, I am going to describe it in separate linked question.)