# Backward-compatible SQL query against table with renamed and added column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, backwards-compatibility

Let `t` be an Oracle 11g table with columns `a`, `b`. The `b` column is later renamed to `c` and new `d` column is added.

How to develop an SQL query which works against both database versions? "Works" means:

- returns columns `a`, `c`, `d`
- behaves as `select a, c, d from t` on new version
- behaves as `select a, b as c, null as d from t` on old version

This is similar problem to [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72099453/653539) (actually I didn't want to mix them into single question). The [CTE-based solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72099454/653539) used there is unfortunately not possible here because the number of columns in CTE declaration is fixed while the number of columns in `select *` clause varies.

The only solution I could figure out is based on conversion between XML and relational model (see self-answer). This is sufficient for my case where table is not large. Anyway I am curious if some pure relational solution (based on joins or Oracle-proprietary constructs such as `pivot`s, `model` clause etc.) exists.

Please also note this question is not about returning dynamic number of columns from SQL query. The number of columns is fixed, only the underlying data schema changes. Using `all_tab_cols` is allowed.

Comment: are both tables supposed to be active at the same time? or is this just about preserving the same query/application across two possibly different db structures?

Comment: @Randy second option is true. There is just single table. The table has old structure in first database, new structure in second database. The first database will have new structure some day. Same client (with same SQL query) accesses both databases.

Comment: This is the sort of thing you would use Edition-Based Redefinition for. This allows you to maintain one table with multiple view definitions. You would have your application tell the database what version it's after (probably by connecting to a service which specifies that edition). https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/edition-based-redefinition-11gr2 is a good place to start

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I could figure out so far is based on conversion to XML which is optionally tweaked to some normalized form and then converted back to relations:

```sql
with singlexml(xmlcol) as (
  select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from t') from dual
)
, adapted(xmlcol) as ( -- turn <B> into <C> if any
  select xmltype(replace(xmlcol, 'B>', 'C>'))
  from singlexml
)
select cols.a
     , cols.c
     , cols.d
from adapted
   , xmltable('/ROWSET/ROW'
       passing adapted.xmlcol
       columns a varchar2(32) path 'A'
             , c varchar2(32) path 'C'
             , d varchar2(32) path 'D' -- outputs null if none
     ) cols
```

[Db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f13a48f62a7c502b3ac4ea4e38b0e431) demonstration on two different tables.

Comment: Later appeared trouble: if `t` is large table with many rows and columns, the query might fail with `ORA-04036: PGA memory used by the instance exceeds PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT` error since whole table doesn't fit into XML. If most of columns are not necessary to be in final result, it is better to eliminate them early in `select * ...` query. However, to keep trick working the `*` is still needed but something like `select * except unnecessary_columns from t` is not possible in Oracle, fortunately there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33220953/653539).

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the colum exists and then run the appropriate `SELECT

```
DECLARE
  v_column_exists number := 0;  
BEGIN
  Select count(*) into v_column_exists
    from user_tab_cols
    where upper(column_name) = 'b'
      and upper(table_name) = 't1';

  if (v_column_exists = 1) then
      execute immediate 'select a, b as c, null as d from t1';
  ELSE
      execute immediate 'select a, c, d from t2';
  end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: This is PLSQL, I need SQL. The query serves as an input for some Pentaho component which expects SQL and provides some result with rows and columns to ETL pipeline into which it is deployed. I can't imagine how PLSQL code could mimic it - perhaps something like block returning sys refcursor.