# How, in Oracle, to SELECT FROM a table or another depending on certain criteria?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that must choose from one table if certain criteria is meet or from another if the criteria is different.

In my case i need to select from Table_A if we are on Database_A or from Table_B if we are on Database_B, but the criteria could be a different one.

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, ..., COLUMN_N
FROM
    (if database is Database_A then Table_A
     but if database is Database_B then from Table B
     else... it could be DUAL if any other situation, it will throw an error, but i can manage it)
WHERE
    (my where criteria)
```

How can i do it with pure SQL not PL-SQL? I can use nested queries or WITH or similar stuff, but not "coding". I cannot create tables or views, i can only query the database for data.

I tried using CASE or other options, with no luck.

Comment: Do all of the tables exist on all the instances? E.g. is there a Table_A on Database_B?

Comment: Both tables *must* exist on both instances, otherwise the pure SQL command would not be compilable. If any table does not exist on some instance, it is possible to mimic it using XML or JSON support - it can be still done without PLSQL but it is not typesafe SQL anymore. I solved similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72102095/653539 . I assume you have (like me there) somewhat tied hands so this dirty hack could help you, yet the standard solution would be to have unifying view on both instances.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the database name in the condition criteria and UNION operator to select from the right table.

```sql
    SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, ..., COLUMN_N
    FROM
    (
     SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, ..., COLUMN_N
     FROM TableA
     WHERE ora_database_name = 'DatabaseA'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, ..., COLUMN_N
     FROM TableB
     WHERE ora_database_name = 'DatabaseB'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'ERROR', null, ..., null
     FROM DUAL
     WHERE ora_database_name NOT IN ('DatabaseA', 'DatabaseB')
     )
     WHERE
     (my where criteria)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is the case of selecting from one of two tables then something like this could help:

```sql
WITH
    tab_a AS
        (   Select COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 From TABLE_A  ),   -- It is possible to do the filter here or in the main SQL or both
    tab_b AS
        (   Select COL_1, COL_2, COL_3 From TABLE_B  )    -- It is possible to do the filter here or in the main SQL or both

Select DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN a.COL_1 ELSE b.COL_1 END "COL_1",
    CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN a.COL_2 ELSE b.COL_2 END "COL_2",
    CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN a.COL_3 ELSE b.COL_3 END "COL_3"
From
    tab_a a
Inner Join
    tab_b b ON(1 = 1)
Where
    CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN b.COL_1 ELSE a.COL_2 END = 'XXX'   -- filter could be set on the same columns or on different ones of the same type
```

You can put the where clause either in the cte definition (WITH clause) or in the main SQL or in both.

- WHEN condition within CASE expresions should be put acording to your data context and that is the place that will select/filter the data from one or another table.
- INNER JOIN ON condition may stay as is (1=1) for it creates cross link that will be solved by the DISTINCT keyword.

If both tables are not reachable from both databases then you shall have a separate scripts, one for each db. You can, though, check which is the active db and/or if there is a specific table.

```sql
-- to get the db name ...
Select NAME "DB_NAME" From V$database

-- ... to check if the table exist ...
Select TABLE_NAME from ALL_TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_A'

-- ... or some additional info besides the table name
Select
    u.USER_ID, u.USERNAME,
    t.TABLE_NAME, t.OWNER "TABLE_OWNER"
From ALL_USERS u
Inner Join ALL_TABLES t ON(t.OWNER = u.USERNAME)
Where TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_A'
```